# Could not set unknown property 'httpAddress' for object of type com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension

Tags: android, backend, google-cloud-endpoints

I have the following code in **build.gradle** file.

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
    }
  }

 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

 dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.9'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'

}
appengine {
    httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

I have my backend for my Android App and I wanted to test it using a physical device. As per this [guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/77e9910911d5412e5efede5fa681ec105a0f02ad/HelloEndpoints#211-testing-device-registration-on-a-physical-device), I added

```
appengine {
httpAddress = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

But I get the following error

> Could not set unknown property 'httpAddress' for object of type com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.appengine.core.AppEngineExtension.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle-reference), you want this:

```
appengine {
  run {
    host = '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```

or

```
appengine.run.host = '0.0.0.0'
```